Must people be informed they are terminally ill?
In Judaism, do doctors or other informed parties have a halachic obligation to tell a person he is terminally ill?  Or to lie to him by telling him his affliction is treatable?
Of course, one can argue that hope is ever present, but I am talking only about communicating statistics based on the record, nothing more.  One can also argue that a person has the right to know so he can prepare.  Anything on the matter from our Sages?

And of course, you can draw a line between "are they allowed to lie and say it will be fine", and "are they allowed to simply say nothing"?

No person is a statistic. The Rebbe always said Hashem gave doctors the remit to heal, not to offer predictions and demoralize their patients. See here and here for examples.

https://ph.yhb.org.il/08-14-01/

@Deuteronomy -- interesting, but offers really no halachic insights.  It's just saying that if YOU think that knowledge is going to harm him more than help him, don't tell him.  It's fully subjective, not halachic.

@shmosel -- What did the Rebbe say the doctor should say when the patient asks him for the statistics of his condition, based on the factual record?
